# ¿Por que no me aparece la carpeta "layout" al crear un proyecto en Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

[image: porque de ahi no me aparece el activity_main.xml]

Es la primera vez que trabajo con android estudio y no se que pude haber hecho mal

Comment: Hola! Por que deberia aparecer la carpeta? Estas seguro que se crea por default? Tal vez la tener que crear vos. 
Otra situacion puede ser que la carpeta exista en el filesystem pero que no este incorporada al proyecto, para ver si existe abri un explorador de carpetas de windows y navega hasta el root del proyecto y fijate si esta. Si no esta, creala, si esta, right click en el proyecto -> agregar carpeta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tienes una carpeta **layout** porque seguramente iniciaste un proyecto de [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose).

Jetpack Compose es una forma nueva y más rápida de crear aplicaciones con programación declarativa.

Deduzco que ese es tu caso en base al código que se puede leer. La anotación `@Composable` pertenece a Jetpack Compose y solo se puede programar en Kotlin.

Si quieres programar de forma tradicional, por vistas, [crea un nuevo proyecto](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/create-project?hl=es-419#:%7E:text=If%20you%20don%27t%20have,Project%20from%20the%20main%20menu.) con alguna plantilla que no diga Compose, ni TV, ni nada de relojes inteligentes a menos que eso quieras.

[image: Crear un proyecto nuevo]

---

Por cierto, si necesitas una carpeta que no está, siempre puedes [crearla](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/add-resources#add_resource_directory).

En este caso, necesitarías ir a **File > New > Android resource directory**.

Answer (score 1):

Es fácil amigo  yo también tuve el mismo problema, en donde dice app en la carpeta de tu proyecto le las clip derecho ... luego New -> XML -> layout XML new .. con esto se crea un carpeta con el nombre layout así de facil .. espero te sea útil. te dejo una imagen [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]