# Problema con la compatibilidad en android studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Estoy aprendiendo Android Studio apenas, y al hacer mi primer activity tuve algunos problemas pero los resolvi, al momento de agregar la segunda activity y hacerle la funcion de que pase de una a otra o al menos eso intente, segui un tutorial de YT al pie de la letra, pero y al momento de querer probarlo me marca el siguiente error:

> This version (1.4.3) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.8.10 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.9.0 which is not known to be compatible.  Please consult the Compose-Kotlin compatibility map located at https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin to choose a compatible version pair (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!)

Ya revise el link que me manda lo implemente en mi gradle pero sigue igual.

Comment: Bienvenido. Si estás desarrollando una app tradicional con Kotlin la respuesta está [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/596767/169744).

Answer (score 0):

La version 1.9.0 de kotlin no es compatible con la version 1.4.3 de compose que tienes usando.

Tienes 2 maneras de solucionar esto. Cambiando la version de kotlin o de compose.

#### Cambiando version de compose

En el build.gradle (app) debes de cambiar a la version 1.5.2 de compose.

```
android {
   composeOptions {
      kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
   }
}
```

#### Cambiando la version de kotlin

La version de kotlin a 1.8.10 en el build.gradle (proyect).

```
plugins {
   id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.10" apply false
}
```

Te dejo una tabla con lista de versiones compatibles:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin

Comment: Bienvenido. No sabemos si quiere trabajar con Compose o no. Es mejor dar respuestas que no requieran aclaraciones o abstenerse hasta tener la información necesaria.